# how to handle checkbox in listview android?

Tags: android, listview

I am using checkbox with ListView.Code is working fine. I strucked to get all the list checked Items. I used below code for getting checked items. But it is giving result of focused area of list.

```
int firstPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        for(int i = firstPosition; i < list.getCount(); i++){
            View v = list.getChildAt(i);
            if(v != null){
                cbx = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.c_checkbox);
                if(cbx.isChecked()){
                                        //adding this check box to one sub list
                }
            }
        }
```

But it is giving only focusable list items result only.Depending on sublist I want to populate my menu that's why I am using this code in onPrepareOptionsMen() method and clicking on menu item delete this list from database.
I found another solution that is

```
long checkedPos[] =list.getCheckedItemIds();
```

But it is giving

> 01-31 12:07:16.042:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(294): VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 808:
>   Landroid/widget/ListView;.getCheckedItemIds
>   ()[J 01-31 12:07:16.042:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(294): VFY:  rejecting
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0024

This error. After searching on Google I found another solution that is

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/368d0bae027aab63/1c61f007e821ed2a?q=%22Getting+the+state+of+a+checkbox+inside+of+a+listview%22+%22Romain+Guy%22#1c61f007e821ed2a

but I want to use SparseBooleanArray  into my activity onPrepareOptionMenu().How to get back this result into my activity from my adapter.Please give me advice?

At last i used SparseBooleanArray.Now it is working fine.
Regards,
Android developer

Comment: D'you set choiceMode to something defferent than CHOICE_MODE_NONE (see setChoiceMode docs)

Comment: I defaut one is not usable in my case that's why I used customised list

Comment: At last i used SparseBooleanArray and it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using SparseBooleanArray in my custom adapter, solved this problem.